# Changing img src with jQuery Flip causes unwanted behavior

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

I'm using jQuery Flip and with this plugin you only have two img elements that you can use, essentially.

What I'm trying to do is obviously have the flip effect working, which works fine, but I have more than two pictures to flip to. Basically, I'm trying to achieve a slideshow effect with this plugin.

[Here's the Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ftxrxtsp/#&togetherjs=j1yymJjcjA)

The problem is that using this plugin, the img being displayed changes live. As in, the image change is shown abruptly, rather than 'flipping' through to that next image. I guess the solution I'm looking for involves changing the `attr` of the `img src` but only show the change after the flip effect has completed? I'm not sure how to approach finding a solution. But, the problem can be clearly seen on the demo. I'm guessing it happens because of how I'm calling the JS attribute change. I don't know.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Thanks to the person that tried editing the fiddle. I looked at the changes and while it has certainly optimized the code, especially the retrieving of the next images in the array, the flashing problem still persists. Thanks anyway.